# Phonegap : Creating simple form and fetching data from android java code

Tags: android, cordova

Hai Guys i am new to this technology.
I have used Cordova and created a Helloworld application.
in index page i have added a form with text button and when i submit i want to fetch data from that text box and Display a toast.
I just don't know how to begin with phonegap some how i have tried doing some thing by learning things from "phonegap.org" .
If u know any blog or site where i can learn this things please provide the link.
And please note that my actual need is that i want to design forms with css,Html,js and do background process in android coding(Java). Is this possible?
Please help me out guys my organization wants me to learn this technology and implement in ongoing project. Thank you for helping

This is my main Activity code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    loadUrl(launchUrl);
}
```

i just want to get the value from the html input tag  and toast it in android

Comment: show your main activity code

Comment: This is wat i have for now. I have just started with phonegap yesterday

Comment: if this is not possible then please provide me an appropriate site where i can learn with basics. My requirement is only to build a form using html and process using java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a plugin (code that bridges your html/js side with native java side) to do that. Here is the documentation for that:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

PS: Normally you would like to do your logic with javascript, not native java. Therefore, you can later use the same code in ios etc. Using phonegap only for UI is not a good idea.